# Pass a varaible to a javascript src='xxx' external include

Tags: javascript, file, variables

My problem is that I have a number of external javascript code blocks in various directories and I need to be able to change the name of each directory as the code is included. I have been looking at this for a while and I am not even sure it can be done.

Example:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wanowandthen.com/"+galleryName+"/getalbumpics.php?id=gallery1"; /script
```

What I want to do is pass a directory name to the variable galleryName so that one HTML file can access a variety of different directories and show the pictures in them.

A copy of the .JS file exists in each directory and all I need is to be able to tell the .JS include statement which directory to use.

Comment: Is `galleryName` a variable coming from JavaScript? If so, you could programmatically create a `script` element, set the `src` attribute with using string concatenation with your variable and append it to the `document.body`.

Comment: In addition to @Marc's question - perhaps `galleryName` is a php variable available server side while you're rendering your page, since you appear to be using php?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very skilled with Javascript. I know what I want to do but have very limited skills to achieve it. My approach is to have a selectable list of gallery names that a reader can pick from. The gallery name - IE. the real folder name - then gets passed to the script above to display the correct image gallery. I will try and work out how to use the solution suggested and thanks all for the help so far. An example of a few gallery pages can be seen at : http://www.wanowandthen.com/gallery-contents.html

Comment: There are many more galleries and it would be great to allow our readers to select any one to display on screen by selecting from a list.

Comment: I have been trying to get this working by using a SELECT statement:    <SELECT>
     <option value="abandoned-western-australia" Selected>Abandoned WA</option> and use a variable 'galleryName' to pass the selection to the Javascript.
     <option value="Albany-gallery" Selected>Albany</option>
   </select>

Answer (score 0):

You should append this to the script that creates the `galleryName` variable:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://www.wanowandthen.com/" + galleryName + "getalbumpics.php?id=gallery1";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT:** This should be the code you need:

```
<form>
  <select onchange="myFunction()" name="galleryName" id="galleryName">
    <option value="abandoned-western-australia" Selected>Abandoned WA</option>
    <option value="Albany-gallery" Selected>Albany</option>
  </select>
</form>


function myFunction() {
    var galleryName = document.getElementById("galleryName").value;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://www.wanowandthen.com/" + galleryName + "getalbumpics.php?id=gallery1";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log(galleryName);
}
```

Comment: Could someone please explain what lines 1 and 4 of the solution actually do. I am a total novice when it comes to writing JS. Thanks.

Comment: It is really DOM manipulation. Line 1 creates tge script and line 4 appends it to the body of the HTML document.

Comment: I must still be missing something here. This is what I have tried to do:

Comment: <form>
      <select name="galleryName" id="galleryName">
     <option value="abandoned-western-australia" Selected>Abandoned WA</option>
     <option value="Albany-gallery" Selected>Albany</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
     
    </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('the name you selected is: ' + galleryName);
   
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://www.wanowandthen.com/" + galleryName + "getalbumpics.php?id=gallery1";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
   
   </script>

Comment: The first document.write is just to see if the correct name is being selected - at present it isn't. As you can tell I am a real novice in all this.

Comment: I have put the version I am working on online at: http://www.wanowandthen.com/any-gallery.html

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the latest version but I still seem to be missing something. I have put the function up in the <HEAD> section of the HTML and it seems to be getting the correct name passed to it but for some reason the images aren't displaying.

Comment: I have tried going back to the original script just to make sure I haven't stuffed up the code and that seems to work Ok. I'm not sure if I have done something wrong in implementing your suggested code...